# Same string but different bytes codes

Tags: ruby

I have two strings:

```
a = 'hà nội'
b = 'hà nội'
```

When I compare them with `a == b`, it returns `false`.

I checked the byte codes:

```
a.bytes = [104, 97, 204, 128, 32, 110, 195, 180, 204, 163, 105]
b.bytes = [104, 195, 160, 32, 110, 225, 187, 153, 105]
```

What is the cause? How can I fix it so that `a == b` returns `true`?

Answer (score 15):

This is an issue with [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

In order to compare these strings you need to normalize them, so that they both use the same byte sequences for these types of characters.

```
a.unicode_normalize == b.unicode_normalize
```

---

`unicode_normalize(form=:nfc)` [[link]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize)

> Returns a normalized form of str, using Unicode normalizations NFC,
>   NFD, NFKC, or NFKD. The normalization form used is determined by form,
>   which is any of the four values :nfc, :nfd, :nfkc, or :nfkd. The
>   default is :nfc.
>
> If the string is not in a Unicode Encoding, then an Exception is
>   raised. In this context, 'Unicode Encoding' means any of UTF-8,
>   UTF-16BE/LE, and UTF-32BE/LE, as well as GB18030, UCS_2BE, and
>   UCS_4BE. Anything else than UTF-8 is implemented by converting to
>   UTF-8, which makes it slower than UTF-8.