# What is the difference between these two character encodings: "å" (195, 165) and "å" (97, 204, 138)

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Both of these byte sequences seem to render correctly in Chrome and my text editor, but the latter is causing some layout problems in a PDF document.

Here are the byte sequences (in decimal):

- å: `195, 165`
- å: `97, 204, 138`

I can see that `195, 165` is the expected sequence for UTF-8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#On_computers

Is `97, 204, 138` also a valid way to encode the character for a UTF-8 string? Or is this a different encoding that just happens to work in some contexts?

I am using the Ruby programming language. Is there any way that I could detect when a user submits this kind of character using the `97, 204, 138` encoding, and safely convert these characters into the `195, 165` encoding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same string but different bytes codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472375/same-string-but-different-bytes-codes)

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered that the first å character is a single character called: "latin small letter a with ring above".

[image: single character]

The second å character is a plain letter "a" followed by the "combining ring above" character, so it's actually two separate characters that are merged together.

[image: two characters]

I used this service to inspect the characters: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect

To answer the second part of the question, Ruby does have a `#unicode_normalize` method that will automatically convert the two character `97, 204, 138` sequence into a single character: `195, 165`.

There are multiple ways to normalize Unicode (NFD, NFC, NFKD and NFKC), so this article goes into much more detail: [Unicode Normalization in Ruby](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-unicode-normalization/)

Comment: That's basic Unicode knowledge - there's much to explore for you, i.e. what can be a space and/or linebreak, where does case folding fail, invalid code points/sequences, overlong encodings... including juggling between a code point and its UTF-8 sequence - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks and https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768